# Is there any simplier/better way to auto-size the content of one-column ListView?

Tags: wpf, listview, listviewitem, autosize

Alright, sorry for my english in advance, here what I need:

I got a `ListView` in **XAML** (WPF) where there items is located and what I need is that items to have the width equal to the `ListView`'s width.

So far, I did this:

```
<ListView Name="lvFiles" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName="lvFiles", Path=ActualWidth}">
                    <!-- All the controls inside I need to present an item -->
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

But as it turned out, the `ListView` items become clipped on the right when the vertical scrollbar appears. And it appears when the total height of all items exceeds the `ListView.ActualHeight`, so I needed to user bindings more complex and hence more complicated.

Also, my items, while I was spending hours to solve the problem, my items sometimes were clipped on the right with no obvious reason.

So I came up with this:

```
<ListView Name="lvFiles" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn Width="{Binding ElementName=lvFiles, Path=ActualWidth}">
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Decorator Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                           Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListViewItem},
                           Path=ActualWidth}">

                    <Grid Margin="0,0,18,0">
                        <!-- All the controls inside... -->
                    </Grid>
                </Decorator>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

It solved clipping problem and also it solved the problem with one-columned `ListViewItem` auto-size. But now it seems to be not the simpliest way. Is there any such?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using a header so you can use `ListView` directly without using `GridView`. As for the width, don't adjust the content width, but adjust the `ListViewItem` width.

Here's an example:

```
<Style x:Key="singleListViewItemStyle"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}}"
       TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Width"
            Value="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type VirtualizingStackPanel}}}" />
</Style>
```

If you do not have an existing style targeting `ListViewItem` or do not want to inherit from it, you can remove `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}}"`.

`AncestorType={x:Type VirtualizingStackPanel}` is used because by default, that is what `ListView` displays its content in. If you have your own `ListView` theme, then see the following example:

```
<ListView Name="myListView"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=singleListViewItemStyle}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyItems}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=MySelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!--Your favorite controls-->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Here is the [link](http://www.filefat.com/nglwa8ggnjcy) for a demo project I made for you. You can also see my other controls.

I hope this helps.

Comment: In this case I can't see my fav controls or any items at all. The ListView is empty.

Comment: @AgentFire Use Snoop to See where did you go Wrong... I can tell you it works that way...

Comment: @AgentFire Check link for Demo project